# How to make striped post background color in Blogger blog homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, blogger

I am customizing Blogger's default theme named [Simple Dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaRKQ.png) but I'm stuck in making the post background color (in the homepage) striped. [This is how my blog looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuiTV.png) and [this is an example](https://www.templateism.com/p/preview.html?url=https://torrenttheme.blogspot.com/&download=http://templateism.com/blogger-templates/Torrentism_Free.zip&buy=http://templateism.com/go/signup/index/c/torrentism) of what I'm trying to achieve. I tried to study the code for the template but I just don't understand.

Comment: Simplest way is with css `:nth-child(even)` selector. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: I've tried this but it only show as striped when multiple posts are posted on the same day.    If the date is different, it won't show the stripe color.

Comment: Hard to help with seeing example code.

Answer (score 1):

Look into :nth-child CSS selector

If each post row has the class `post`, you can use it like this to use different styles for even and odd posts:

```
.post:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

.post:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

You can also alternate between more than two styles.
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child